# How to import a local library that resolves its dependencies from a different gradle project (using buildSrc)?

Tags: android, ios, kotlin, gradle, kotlin-multiplatform

So recently we have been creating KMM modules for our native iOS and Android apps. Our previous way of doing things using Swift Packages ended up being too complicated and error prone for local testing of the kmm code on iOS.

In an effort to make our iOS dev teams life easier, we have created a Kmm "meta project". The goal was to have the iOS devs change one line of code in the ios app Podfile, to switch from pointing to a single Kmm bridge project that itself points to multiple maven Kmm libraries, to a Local kmm bridge project that points to all the local Kmm subprojects that include libraries and sample apps for each library (for local testing and development).

***Also, the main goal of this meta project that wraps multiple subprojects was to use a root buildSrc directory to have one place to define dependencies and their versions, to ensure consistent versioning throughout all our Kmm libraries. All the dependencies are defined in a file called Dependencies.kt***

Long story short, this method functions quite well for the iOS developers. The problem arrives when we try to import one of the local kmm libraries into our Android app, for local testing during development.

Because our android app is contained in a Gradle project that defines it's own buildSrc and Dependencies.kt file, importing one of the kmm libraries as a local library does not work, **I am guessing because the dependencies are defined in another gradle project**.

So my question is:

1. Is it possible to "import" an external BuildSrc kotlin file in another project to help gradle resolve the kmm library dependency?
2. If not #1, can I define libraries and shared dependencies somewhere else, and be able to have the meta project as well as another project resolve the dependencies for the kmm libraries?

Here is a diagram of our current architecture, that illustrates how we have things set up and where the problem arises:

[image: KMM dependency structure]

Open to any suggestions or solutions. I am thinking there has to be a way to get dependency definitions that can be shared cross-project, like some sort of external file or dependency catalog, that can be imported everywhere and can allow the kmm libraries to resolve their own dependencies without the need of a gradle project.

Comment: Have you considered get rid of `buildSrc` and use Gradle [versionCatalog](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/platforms.html) instead?

Comment: @Evgeny I tried this, and I ran into the same problem. The android app project cannot find the dependencies defined in the library.